# How to send nextjs server error logs to new relic using via newrelic browser monitoring

Tags: next.js, error-handling, newrelic, server-error

I am using Newrelic script to add Browser monitoring but i am unable to get error on servers my error component is unable to send server error

Added

```
Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
console.log("statusCode err", res, err);
if (typeof window == "undefined") {
const newrelic = require("newrelic");
newrelic.noticeError(err);
} else {
window.newrelic.noticeError(err);
}
const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
return { statusCode };
};

e
```

xport default Error;
can we use this newrelic.noticeError(err) when newrelic instaled via script

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Newrelic Browser won't be capturing any error on server-side executed code we need to add a new relic agent to get server logs and error reporting.